# How to get word count of a part of a line

Tags: bash, awk

The lines of the files are as something like this .

```
<some character> ||| each line. So far i can get the total number of lines and the text for each on its own line ||| <some text>
```

Now I want to count the no of words in between the `|||`.

What I intended to do is

`awk -F '|||' '{print $2}' word_file | wc -l`

but it throws blank in the awk part ,which suggests it is not taking `|||` as I want (which is as a delimiter ),interestingly if i use `$1` instead of `$2` ,it prints the whole text

However if I use `|||` (i.e a `space` before and after) it gives me some output but does not treat the sentence between the two delimeters as one field ,i.e it prints `each` instead of the whole sentence if I use the following

`awk -F ' ||| ' '{print $2}' word_file`

How do I achieve this using a bash command

FYI
    `awk version -GNU Awk 4.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Awk's `-F` option, which sets `FS`, the input-field separator, expects a *regular expression* as its value.

Thus, for `|||` to be interpreted as a *literal*, you must `\`-escape the `|` chars, which are metacharacters in a regex context.

Given that Awk also accepts `\`-based escape sequences in string *literals*, you must *double* the `\` instances:
`awk -F '\\|\\|\\|' ...`

To properly count the words (defined as whitespace-separated tokens) in field 2, you can try this:

```
awk -F '\\|\\|\\|' 'BEGIN { orgFs=FS } { FS=" "; $0 = $2; print NF; FS=orgFS }' word_file
```

This splits each input line into fields by *literal* `|||`.

By *temporarily* setting `FS` to a single space - which is a magic value that tells Awk to split into fields by *any nonempty run of whitespace* - we can assign `$2`, the value of field 2, to `$0`, the whole input line, which causes the new value of `$0` to be split into fields again.

At that point `NF` reflects the number of fields in what was originally the 2nd field - i.e., the number of words - and we can print that.

Restoring `FS` to its original value then prepares for parsing the next input line.

Answer (score 0):

with `gawk` multi-char RS support, this might be easier

```
$ awk -v RS="\\\|\\\|\\\|" 'NR==2{print NF}' file
```

or if not sure how to escape the pipe, perhaps cleaner with

```
$ awk -v RS='[|]{3}' ...
```